# Is there any way to generate my old keystore file?

Tags: react-native, google-play-services, android-keystore, android-app-signing, app-signing

[image]

I tried to create new release on playstore for my react-native app.But it gave this error(Check above img).I lost the upload key which I use to sign each release.

I have no permission to request key upgrade or playstore contact support as I haven't logging to email which use to create playstore console.(check below img.)

[image]

I want to create new release to playstore.I want to know is there any way to generate my old keystore file with password?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem a few days, i solved my problem by creating a new key and new app on the playstore, I recommend you to save the keystor9e on various backups.